# calling SP from within another SP gives different result

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure that fetches an int from a table and updates the table.
This is the complete stored procedure

```
create procedure spGetNewVMacsBatchNumber as
begin
    set nocount on
    declare @LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber int

    update tblSettings with (TABLOCK)
    set    LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber = isnull(LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber, 0) + 1,
           @LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber = isnull(LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber, 0) + 1

    select @LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber
end;
```

When I run this from SSMS it does what I expect from it, return the number + 1 and update the table.
I call it in SSMS like this :

```
declare @BatchNumber int
exec @BatchNumber = spGetNewVMacsBatchNumber
```

But when I call it from within another stored procedure it does not returns the value I expect, but always returns zero. The call in the other stored procedure is exact the same as above.

How can I call this stored procedure from another stored procedure and still get the value I expect ?

The idea for spGetNewVMacsBatchNumber is to retrieve the current value + 1 and to make sure it does not returns a wrong value when 2 processes run it at the same time.
Maybe there is a better way of doing that then my approach ?

Comment: Have you considered just using an `output` clause on the `update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should actually use `output parameters` for your procedure.

```
alter procedure spGetNewVMacsBatchNumber @ReturnVal int output as
begin
    set nocount on
    declare @LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber int

    update tblSettings with (TABLOCK)
    set    LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber = isnull(LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber, 0) + 1,
           @LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber = isnull(LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber, 0) + 1

    select @ReturnVal = @LastUsedVMacsBatchNumber
end;
```

And then call it like this:

```
declare @BatchNumber int
exec spGetNewVMacsBatchNumber @ReturnVal= @BatchNumber output;
select @BatchNumber
```

You are getting the `return status` of the `spGetNewVMacsBatchNumber` stored procedure like that, not the actual *"return value"* from the stored proc.

Comment: Thanks this works. I always thought that a stored procedure returns the last select statement. I guess I was wrong